# How to use an AdminBasePage inherited from BasePage(which is inherited from WebPage) in Apache wicket

Tags: java, apache, wicket

I am using Apache Wicket Framework in my java web application project. I have a BasePage which is inherited from Apache Wicket's WebPage.

I need an AdminBasePage which is inherited from BasePage to authanticate users while access admin pages but it gives an error that i can't render html markup, it says that may be i added code to java class but forgot to add html markup.

Here is my BasePage:

Html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>BasePage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <wicket:child>

        </wicket:child>
    </body>
</html>
```

Java:
    package com.myapp.wicket;

```
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;

public abstract class BasePage extends WebPage{

    public BasePage () {
        super();
    }
}
```

---

Here is my AdminBasePage:

Html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>AdminBasePage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Java:
    package com.myapp.wicket.admin;

```
import com.myapp.wicket.BasePage;

public abstract class AdminBasePage extends BasePage {

    public AdminBasePage() {
        super();
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong? What should i do? Can you suggest me anything to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the following in AdminBasePage's markup:

```
<wicket:extend>
</wicket:extend>
```

... or just remove AdminBasePage.html

Read more here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/markup-inheritance.html